# Chrome API - Making active tab go back in history more than once

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get my Chrome extension to make the currently active tab go back in history more than once.

Why does this code only make the active tab go back once, instead of 5 times, like it's supposed to?:

```
goBackOnePage(0);

function goBackOnePage(count) {

  // Get currently active tab in current window.
  chrome.tabs.query({ 
    'active': true,
    'lastFocusedWindow': true
  }, function(tabs) {

    var activeTabId = tabs[0].id;

    // Execute history.back() script on active tab.
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(activeTabId, {
      code: 'history.back();'
    }, function(result) {

      // Recurse 5 times.
      if ( count++ < 5 ) {
        console.log(activeTabId); // This gets logged 5 times (recursion working)
        goBackOnePage( count ); 
      }
    });
  });
}
```

The active tab goes back one page, but no more.  The log gets called 5 times and logs the exact same active tab id 5 times.  Why doesn't the active tab go back 5 times?
I also tried wrapping the recursive call in a setTimeout method (500ms) and even created a thread-pausing method (essentially), but it was the same problem.

Comment: `window.history.go(-5);` ?

Comment: Trying to perform operations at each step backwards in history, though.  I'm creating an extension that saves an open tab along with the history of that particular tab, so the user remembers how they got there.